# How can I fix "PartialOrd is not implemented for HashMap" error?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I am writing an interpreter in Rust and came across this error that I don't know how to solve. It is caused by including `HashMap` one of my enum variants:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// stubbed type
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Eq, PartialOrd, Hash)]
struct Expression;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Eq, PartialOrd, Hash)]
enum Literal {
    Integer(i64),
    Bool(bool),
    String(String),
    Array(Vec<Expression>),
    Hash(HashMap<Expression, Expression>),
}
```

```
error[E0277]: can't compare `HashMap<Expression, Expression>` with `HashMap<Expression, Expression>`
  --> src/lib.rs:13:10
   |
7  | #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Eq, PartialOrd, Hash)]
   |                                       ---------- in this derive macro expansion
...
13 |     Hash(HashMap<Expression, Expression>),
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no implementation for `HashMap<Expression, Expression> < HashMap<Expression, Expression>` and `HashMap<Expression, Expression> > HashMap<Expression, Expression>`
   |
   = help: the trait `PartialOrd` is not implemented for `HashMap<Expression, Expression>`

error[E0277]: the trait bound `HashMap<Expression, Expression>: Hash` is not satisfied
  --> src/lib.rs:13:10
   |
7  | #[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Clone, Eq, PartialOrd, Hash)]
   |                                                   ---- in this derive macro expansion
...
13 |     Hash(HashMap<Expression, Expression>),
   |          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Hash` is not implemented for `HashMap<Expression, Expression>`
```

The error says that `PartialOrd` is not implemented for `HashMap<Expression, Expression>`, but to my understanding `HashMap` is unordered so why would I need that?

What do I need to do to fix it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: And also post the error from `cargo check`, not your IDE (rust-analyzer now has "Click for full compiler diagnostic").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Above your type you have `#[derive(..., PartialOrd, ...)]`. This means that all enum variants should implement `PartialOrd`. That's why the compiler wants `HashMap<Expression, Expression>` to implement `PartialOrd`.

Either remove the `HashMap` from the variant, remove `PartialOrd` from the `#[derive(...)]`, or use a map type that implements `PartialOrd` like [`BTreeMap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.BTreeMap.html).

And the same goes for the `Hash` trait.

Comment: Thanks! I swapped the HashMap with BTreeMap and it worked because PartialOrd doesn't conflict with BTreeMap